# Git Bash command line not launching correctly

Tags: git, bash, git-bash

[image: Git Bash Screenshot]

Recently when trying to use the Git Bash, I noticed that it would open up but I was unable to enter any text in the window to execute a command. A few weeks back, I updated to windows 8.1. I have had multiple people work with me to figure this out but no solution has been found. Is there anyone else that has had this problem that can help me? I have provided a screenshot of the open Git Bash.

Comment: What command are you using to start Git Bash?

Comment: Any difference with run as administrator?

Comment: Running as admin does not change it. I use the desktop icon to start it up. It is the icon that you can see on the left portion of the screenshot.

Comment: The target for the link on my win7 machine looks like: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i"`  You should have a similar setting in the properties for your shortcut.  What happens if you exec that command from a new cmd shell?

Comment: Okay since I corrected the path for it, it now allows me to enter in commands such as cd and such, but when I enter in git, it says " 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."  So I assume there is still a problem with the paths because it can not find 'git' or its commands.